# Spark Streaming - Dstream messages in json format to DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I'm trying to read Kafka topics through Apache Spark Streaming and am not able to figure out how to transform the data in DStream to DataFrame and then store in a temp table. The messages in Kafka are in Avro format, which were created by Kafka JDBC Connect from a database. I have the below code, which works fine until it executes  the `spark.read.json` to read the json to dataframe.

```
package consumerTest


import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SQLContext, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010._

import scala.util.parsing.json.{JSON, JSONObject}

object Consumer {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder
      .master("local")
      .appName("my-spark-app")
      .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
      .getOrCreate();

    import spark.implicits._


    val ssc = new StreamingContext(spark.sparkContext, Seconds(10))

    val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
      "bootstrap.servers" -> "<kafka-server>:9092",
      "key.deserializer" -> classOf[KafkaAvroDeserializer],
      "value.deserializer" -> classOf[KafkaAvroDeserializer],
      "group.id" -> "sakwq",
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest",
      "enable.auto.commit" -> "false",
      "schema.registry.url" -> "http://<schema-registry>:8181"
    )

    val topics = Array("cdcemployee")

    val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, Object](
      ssc,
      PreferConsistent,
      Subscribe[String, Object](topics, kafkaParams)
    )


    val data = stream.map(record => {
      println(record.value.toString())
      record.value
      val df = spark.read.json(record.value.toString())

    })


    data.print();



    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }


}
```

I am getting a Null pointer exception when executing the line  `val df = spark.read.json(record.value.toString())`

```
18/05/10 09:49:11 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.<init>(DataFrameReader.scala:689)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.read(SparkSession.scala:645)
    at consumerTest.Consumer$.$anonfun$main$1(Consumer.scala:63)
    at consumerTest.Consumer$.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(Consumer.scala:60)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:393)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1354)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1354)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2069)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2069)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
18/05/10 09:49:11 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.<init>(DataFrameReader.scala:689)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.read(SparkSession.scala:645)
    at consumerTest.Consumer$.$anonfun$main$1(Consumer.scala:63)
    at consumerTest.Consumer$.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(Consumer.scala:60)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:393)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1354)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1354)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2069)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2069)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Also, here is the sample data that gets printed when executing the statement `println(record.value.toString())` if I remove the `spark.read.json` statement

```
    {"CDCTRANSACTIONID": 182241, "CDCTIMESTAMP": "2018-03-26 18:04:44:776 - 04:00", "CDCCHANGESEQ": 14, "CDCCONTINUATIONPOSITION": 0, "CDCARRAYINDEX": 0, "CDCFRAGMENT": 0, "CDCOPERATION": 4, "EmpNum": 57, "LastName": null, "FirstName": null, "Address": null, "Address2": null, "City": "San Francisco", "State": null, "PostalCode": null, "DeptCode": "300", "Position": null, "HomePhone": null, "WorkPhone": null, "VacationDaysLeft": null, "SickDaysLeft": null, "StartDate": null, "Birthdate": null}
{"CDCTRANSACTIONID": 182241, "CDCTIMESTAMP": "2018-03-26 18:04:44:776 - 04:00", "CDCCHANGESEQ": 14, "CDCCONTINUATIONPOSITION": 0, "CDCARRAYINDEX": 0, "CDCFRAGMENT": 0, "CDCOPERATION": 3, "EmpNum": 57, "LastName": null, "FirstName": null, "Address": null, "Address2": null, "City": "Raleigh", "State": null, "PostalCode": null, "DeptCode": "", "Position": null, "HomePhone": null, "WorkPhone": null, "VacationDaysLeft": null, "SickDaysLeft": null, "StartDate": null, "Birthdate": null}
{"CDCTRANSACTIONID": 197086, "CDCTIMESTAMP": "2018-03-27 11:18:48:022 - 04:00", "CDCCHANGESEQ": 15, "CDCCONTINUATIONPOSITION": 0, "CDCARRAYINDEX": 0, "CDCFRAGMENT": 0, "CDCOPERATION": 4, "EmpNum": 57, "LastName": null, "FirstName": null, "Address": null, "Address2": null, "City": "New York", "State": null, "PostalCode": null, "DeptCode": null, "Position": null, "HomePhone": null, "WorkPhone": null, "VacationDaysLeft": null, "SickDaysLeft": null, "StartDate": null, "Birthdate": null}
{"CDCTRANSACTIONID": 197086, "CDCTIMESTAMP": "2018-03-27 11:18:48:022 - 04:00", "CDCCHANGESEQ": 15, "CDCCONTINUATIONPOSITION": 0, "CDCARRAYINDEX": 0, "CDCFRAGMENT": 0, "CDCOPERATION": 3, "EmpNum": 57, "LastName": null, "FirstName": null, "Address": null, "Address2": null, "City": "San Francisco", "State": null, "PostalCode": null, "DeptCode": null, "Position": null, "HomePhone": null, "WorkPhone": null, "VacationDaysLeft": null, "SickDaysLeft": null, "StartDate": null, "Birthdate": null}
{"CDCTRANSACTIONID": 363712, "CDCTIMESTAMP": "2018-04-04 15:30:46:551 - 04:00", "CDCCHANGESEQ": 16, "CDCCONTINUATIONPOSITION": 0, "CDCARRAYINDEX": 0, "CDCFRAGMENT": 0, "CDCOPERATION": 4, "EmpNum": 57, "LastName": null, "FirstName": null, "Address": null, "Address2": null, "City": "San Diego", "State": null, "PostalCode": null, "DeptCode": null, "Position": null, "HomePhone": null, "WorkPhone": null, "VacationDaysLeft": null, "SickDaysLeft": null, "StartDate": null, "Birthdate": null}
{"CDCTRANSACTIONID": 363712, "CDCTIMESTAMP": "2018-04-04 15:30:46:551 - 04:00", "CDCCHANGESEQ": 16, "CDCCONTINUATIONPOSITION": 0, "CDCARRAYINDEX": 0, "CDCFRAGMENT": 0, "CDCOPERATION": 3, "EmpNum": 57, "LastName": null, "FirstName": null, "Address": null, "Address2": null, "City": "New York", "State": null, "PostalCode": null, "DeptCode": null, "Position": null, "HomePhone": null, "WorkPhone": null, "VacationDaysLeft": null, "SickDaysLeft": null, "StartDate": null, "Birthdate": null}
{"CDCTRANSACTIONID": 363785, "CDCTIMESTAMP": "2018-04-04 15:35:11:492 - 04:00", "CDCCHANGESEQ": 17, "CDCCONTINUATIONPOSITION": 0, "CDCARRAYINDEX": 0, "CDCFRAGMENT": 0, "CDCOPERATION": 2, "EmpNum": 57, "LastName": "bobba2s", "FirstName": "Saikrishna Teja", "Address": "9220 Bothwell St", "Address2": "", "City": "San Diego", "State": "NC", "PostalCode": "27617", "DeptCode": "300", "Position": "", "HomePhone": "919 931-5737", "WorkPhone": "919 931-5737", "VacationDaysLeft": 10, "SickDaysLeft": 5, "StartDate": 16979, "Birthdate": 7270}
{"CDCTRANSACTIONID": 364688, "CDCTIMESTAMP": "2018-04-04 16:39:05:602 - 04:00", "CDCCHANGESEQ": 18, "CDCCONTINUATIONPOSITION": 0, "CDCARRAYINDEX": 0, "CDCFRAGMENT": 0, "CDCOPERATION": 1, "EmpNum": 59, "LastName": "Bobba", "FirstName": "Saikrishna Teja", "Address": "9220 Bothwell St", "Address2": "", "City": "Raleigh", "State": "NC", "PostalCode": "27617", "DeptCode": "300", "Position": "", "HomePhone": "919 931-5737", "WorkPhone": "919 931-5737", "VacationDaysLeft": 10, "SickDaysLeft": 5, "StartDate": 16979, "Birthdate": 7270}
{"CDCTRANSACTIONID": 384368, "CDCTIMESTAMP": "2018-04-05 15:43:15:478 - 04:00", "CDCCHANGESEQ": 19, "CDCCONTINUATIONPOSITION": 0, "CDCARRAYINDEX": 0, "CDCFRAGMENT": 0, "CDCOPERATION": 4, "EmpNum": 59, "LastName": null, "FirstName": null, "Address": null, "Address2": null, "City": "San Francisco", "State": "CA", "PostalCode": null, "DeptCode": null, "Position": null, "HomePhone": null, "WorkPhone": null, "VacationDaysLeft": null, "SickDaysLeft": null, "StartDate": null, "Birthdate": null}
{"CDCTRANSACTIONID": 384368, "CDCTIMESTAMP": "2018-04-05 15:43:15:478 - 04:00", "CDCCHANGESEQ": 19, "CDCCONTINUATIONPOSITION": 0, "CDCARRAYINDEX": 0, "CDCFRAGMENT": 0, "CDCOPERATION": 3, "EmpNum": 59, "LastName": null, "FirstName": null, "Address": null, "Address2": null, "City": "Raleigh", "State": "NC", "PostalCode": null, "DeptCode": null, "Position": null, "HomePhone": null, "WorkPhone": null, "VacationDaysLeft": null, "SickDaysLeft": null, "StartDate": null, "Birthdate": null}
{"CDCTRANSACTIONID": 650254, "CDCTIMESTAMP": "2018-04-18 16:19:35:669 - 04:00", "CDCCHANGESEQ": 20, "CDCCONTINUATIONPOSITION": 0, "CDCARRAYINDEX": 0, "CDCFRAGMENT": 0, "CDCOPERATION": 4, "EmpNum": 59, "LastName": null, "FirstName": null, "Address": null, "Address2": null, "City": "San Diego", "State": null, "PostalCode": null, "DeptCode": null, "Position": null, "HomePhone": null, "WorkPhone": null, "VacationDaysLeft": null, "SickDaysLeft": null, "StartDate": null, "Birthdate": null}
```

Can anyone help me on how to convert this to dataframe and store it temporarily in a table?

edit:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`stream` contains the RDD for each `interval` of time, so for each `interval` time you can convert the `rdd` to datafarme as

```
stream.foreachRDD(rddRaw => {
  val rdd = rddRaw.map(_.value.toString) // or rddRaw.map(_._2)
  val df = spark.read.json(rdd)
})
```

This should give you the dataframe as expected.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work. I'm getting a compile time error message for the statement `spark.read.json(rdd)` that says `Error:(69, 27) overloaded method value json with alternatives:
  (jsonDataset: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (jsonRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (jsonRDD: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD[String])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
(paths: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
(path: String)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
`

Comment: continuing
`cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Object])
      val df = spark.read.json(rdd)`

Comment: I'm seeing the same error after removing `val data =`, unfortunately

Comment: can you share the screenshoot?

Comment: Added the screenshot to the question

Comment: @thedataguy can you try with ` val rdd = rddRaw.map(_.value.toString)' I have no avro data to test.

Comment: That worked, thank you very much for your help.  On a side note, how do I convert this into a temp table, is it registerTempTable or createOrReplaceTempView. There seems to be lot of different ways according to some other threads, want to make sure I'm using the correct method. I'm running Spark 2.2.1 and using Scala 2.11 btw.

Comment: what do you want to do with table ?

Comment: You can use `createOrReplaceTempView`  `registerTempTable` is already depricated

Comment: I'm planning to use this script in zeppelin, modify it a bit to read multiple topics from Kafka and visualize the data by joining it on a common value. A sort of visualization by aggregating the data is my final goal

Answer (score 0):

## Pyspark

**Json Data:**

```
{"timestamp": "1571053218000","t1": "55.23","t2": "10","t3": "ON"}

{"timestamp": "1571053278000","t1": "63.23","t2": "11","t3": "OFF"}

{"timestamp": "1571053338000","t1": "73.23","t2": "12","t3": "ON"}

{"timestamp": "1571053398000","t1": "83.23","t2": "13","t3": "ON"}
```

## Pyspark Code to read from above json data:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, LongType, DecimalType,StructType, StructField, StringType
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession(sc)
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 5)

stream_data = ssc.textFileStream("/filepath/")

def readMyStream(rdd):
  if not rdd.isEmpty():
    df = spark.read.json(rdd)
    print('Started the Process')
    print('Selection of Columns')
    df = df.select('t1','t2','t3','timestamp').where(col("timestamp").isNotNull())
    df.show()

stream_data.foreachRDD( lambda rdd: readMyStream(rdd) )
ssc.start()
ssc.stop()
```